# ES102424A Un sistema de cuaderno de hojas intercambiables

Tags: european, coil

Help me find the Original document of this Patent ES102424A by French Association 'La Reliure Spirale'
'A flip-sheet notebook system' could be the translation, but I could not find the Original document from 1927-06-01

Comment: All the places I looked show the bibliographic info but do not have any images or text.

Comment: Hi George, yes that was my experience as well. But one patent attorney found it at the Spanish Datrabase and sent me the link.

Answer (score 2):

Found it in the [database](https://consultas2.oepm.es/InvenesWeb/faces/busquedaInternet.jsp) of the Spanish PTO: [PDF of the document you are looking for](http://www.oepm.es/pdf/ES/0000/000/00/10/24/ES-0102424_A3.pdf)

Comment: Possibly the best one sentence answer ever. Even without a period.

Comment: Your messages lightenend up my day! I have been searching there, but could not find it. It is a gem!! Thank you so much, Ruth from Vienna